# Can't find Shockwave player object reference in WPF application

Tags: c#, flash, com, adobe, toolbox

I'm trying to use google maps in my `wpf c#` project, I've installed Adobe Flash player but cannot for the life of me find the shockwave player object reference or when I add a new item in the toolbox find in, both in the COM lists.

I've searched everywhere for a answer and have got nothing.
Any ideas?

Problem SOlved!! had to download and install flash using internet explorer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shockwave player is different than Flash player. You need to install the [Shockwave Player](http://get.adobe.com/shockwave/).

**Update**

According to [this very detailed, step-by-step guide](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/flashmapinwpf.html) for hosting Google Maps in a WPF application, you cannot directly use Shockwave in a WPF application since WPF can't host ActiveX controls.

However, you can create a Windows Forms app that contains the ActiveX control, then use the [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) control to host the Windows form in the WPF app.

**Update 2**

If flash or shockwave is installed by a browser other than IE, the OCX will not be installed in the system and thus will not be available in the project.

To resolve this, either run IE and install these items or go to [this Adobe page](http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/alternates/) and seleect the IE versions of the applications.

Comment: Ive got both shockwave and flash player installed and currently in the references im only getting Shockwave ActiveX control and not Shockwave Flash Player Object :/

Comment: @user1073290: Updated the answer with the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thats the tutorial im following and even doing the stages im not getting the shockwave flash reference, im only getting the shockwave activeX control reference...any ideas why?? thanks for the help so far

Comment: @user1073290: Just to clarify, you are trying to get the reference within the winforms app, correct? It won't show up in WPF. I think the correct location for the OCX is something like `C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\`. Can you check there to see if it exists? Also, when I add it, it is just called Shockwave Flash (the COM object). This is actually the player.

Comment: yeh im doing it in a winsforms app and what should i be looking for in macromed/flash?? as the folder exists and yeh i think im looking for shockwave flash

Comment: ive got no OCX in my flash folder :/ but ive got the folder

Comment: @user1073290: If you are on a 64-bit OS, try looking in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash`. Also, if you are on a 64-bit OS, try changing the platform of the project to x86 instead of any cpu or x64.

Comment: in sysWOW64\macromed\flash i got a file called flashplayer.xpt and how do  i change the project to x86? cheers

Comment: Ah, I may know what is happening: did you install flash and shockwave using IE or a different browser? I suspect that the OCX will only be installed for IE. You can also get the IE version from this page: http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/alternates/. To change the platform, select Configuration Manager from the Build menu, then select <New...> from the Active Solution Platform dropdown list and then the appropriate platform in the popup dialog.

Comment: Problem SOlved!! had to download and install flash using internet explorer :D

Comment: That's excellent news! Remember if an answer solves or helps you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark and up arrows next to the answer so that future visitors to the question will know this answer resolved your issue.